# Passing in a global javascript array to jQuery document(ready)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have the following html rendered from templating (jsRender)

```
 <div class="noteActions top" style="z-index: 3;">
 <span onclick="noteAction('add', 13808, 0 );"></span>
 <span onclick="noteAction('update',13808, 106344 );"></span>
 <span onclick="noteAction('delete', 13808, 106344 );"></span>
 </div>
```

My issue is I have a function outside the document ready that is setting a data array that later, a jquery dialog window submits via ajax to the handler to update the database

What's happening is the data array correctly passes everything except the jquery vals by class selector (pr-body, pr-title), they pass as NULL

javascript - outside document (ready)

```
 var updateUrl = 'handlers/Poster.ashx',
 data;
function noteAction(action, prospectID, noteID){
                data = { 
                 'operation': action, 
                 'prospectid':prospectID,                    
                 'note-body' : $('.pr-body').val(),
                 'note-title' : $('.pr-title').val(),
                 'note-id':noteID,
                 };
    if (action == 'add'){
        $( "#dialogPostIt" ).dialog("open", "option", "title", "Add Post It");
    } else if (action == 'update'){
        $( "#dialogPostIt" ).dialog("open", "option", "title", "Edit Post It");
    } else if (action == 'delete'){
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete')) return false;
        $.post(updateUrl+"?operation=delete&noteid="+noteID, function(data) {
        $('#stickyNote-'+noteID).remove();  
        });
    }
}
```

jquery - document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $( "#dialogPostIt" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, modal:true,
buttons: {            
        'Save': function() {
            $.ajax({                    
                url: updateUrl,
                data: data,
                success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
 .....
```

html

```
 <div id="dialogPostIt" >
 <form id="postItNow" action="" method="post" class="note-form">
 <label for="note-title">Title (description)</label>
 <input type="text" name="note-title" id="note-title" class="pr-title" value="" />

 <label for="note-body">Text of the note</label>
 <textarea name="note-body" id="note-body" class="pr-body" cols="30" rows="6">     </textarea>
 </form></div>
```

I previously was setting the data array inside the dialog save button function(), which worked fine, but I needed to make some of the array elements dynamic based on event

The array doesnt have to be global from my requirements, i just couldnt think of another way todo this

As Always, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: _WHY_ are you using inline JS calls with jQuery?

Comment: agreeably not optimal, third-party limitations, going to explore turning into on('click')s, but I dont believe thats the problem with the above code, trying to figure out why only the two selectors are not being passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i feel like a real dope, it actually is working fine, issue was pilot error -_-

The data array was returning the values correctly, problem is there was *no values yet* , as the data was set prior to the subsequent dialog containing the form, so no form vals couldve been filled in yet

the fix

javascript outside the document ready

```
function noteAction(action, prospectID, noteID){
                data = { 
                 'operation': action, 
                 'prospectid':prospectID,                    
                 'notebody' : '',
                 'notetitle' : '',
                 'noteid':noteID,
                 };
```

jquery in dialog (document ready)

```
 $( "#dialogPostIt" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, modal:true,
buttons: {            
        'Save': function() {
            data.notebody = $('.pr-body').val();
            data.notetitle= $('.pr-title').val(),
            $.ajax({                    
                url: updateUrl,
                data: data,
```